# How do I burn Lubuntu 18.04.1 to a LiveDVD in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, laptop, community, livedvd

I am trying to install Lubuntu on a 2002 Gateway, and it appears USB is not an option: Options include CD/DVD-Drive, Floppy, Hard Disk, and LAN.

[The BurningIsoHowTo instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) do not work: Dragging the iso -- I have already verified the MD5 checksum -- to the left pane of Disk Utility does nothing, and File > Open Disk Image > selecting the downloaded iso also does nothing.

I am left with the impression that the instructions are outdated and that asking here is the most efficient means to proceed. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Use any burning utility you want as long as it supports the burning from image file feature. The native utility should work though.

Comment: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2017/02/23/burning-disk-images-to-optical-media-in-macos-sierra/

Comment: Shell commands and GUI hints are given at https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#record-unix

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the Ubuntu ISO.

   The easiest way to burn an Ubuntu ISO on a DVD is by right-clicking on the file in Finder.

- Right-click on the Ubuntu .iso file.
- Select the *Burn Disk Image* option.

  [image]

2. Insert a blank DVD.

   Click the **Burn** button in the lower right corner of the Burn Disc window.

   [image]
3. Burn and verify the DVD.

   The data will be burned and verified.

   [image]

<sub>**Source:** [How to burn a DVD on macOS | Ubuntu tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#0)</sub>